# Order column1 and order column2 in between the values of column1

Tags: sql-server

I want order by col3 on whole result set but order by col2 in between col3

```
col1  col2       col3
---------------------
Abhi  10/3/2019  Sc1
Abhi  10/4/2019  Sc1
Abhi  9/4/2018   Sc1
Abhi  9/4/2018   Sc1
Abhi  3/20/2018  Sc2
Abhi  3/20/2018  Sc2
Abhi  3/20/2017  Sc2
Abhi  3/20/2017  Sc2
```

Result set

[image]

select * from table1 order by col3 , col2

Is not giving my expected result set, I don't want to apply group by clause

Comment: Offhand, the result looks correct. Can you share the result you'd want to get for this sample?

Comment: The problem looks to be col2 is a date value but the column data type is `varchar`. Don't do that. Always specify the correct column data type to ensure data integrity (e.g. valid dates) with natural sorting and comparison.

Comment: What happened to `9/4/2018`?

Comment: Why do you think a GROUP BY clause is helpful or would be a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your dates are stored as varchar, try casting to date type:

```
select * from table1
order by Col3, cast(Col2 as date)
```